# Texture.loadFromFile doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, sfml

Whenever I try to load a texture in a class (Map.cpp) that is not the main one (Main.cpp), the texture image does not appear.

This is the class where the rectangle is created.

```
queue<sf::RectangleShape*> Map::ReadFile(std::string file)
{
    std::queue<sf::RectangleShape*> shapes;
    fstream opened_file;
    opened_file.open(file);
    string line;
    string word;
    int row = 0;

    sf::Vector2f shape_position;
    sf::Vector2f shape_size;

    while (getline(opened_file, line))
    {
        sf::RectangleShape* shape = new sf::RectangleShape;

        for (char& c : line)
        {
            if (c == ';' or c == ',')
            {
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    sf::Texture texture;
                    texture.loadFromFile(word);

                    shape->setTexture(&texture);
                }
                else if (row == 1)
                {
                    shape_position.x = std::stoi(word);
                }
                else if (row == 2)
                {
                    shape_position.y = std::stoi(word);
                }
                else if (row == 3)
                {
                    shape_size.x = std::stoi(word);
                }
                else if (row == 4)
                {
                    shape_size.y = std::stoi(word);
                }

                row++;
                word = "";
            }
            else if (c == ' ')
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                word = word + c;
            }
        }

        word = "";
        row = 0;

        shape->setSize(shape_size);
        shape->setPosition(shape_position);

        shapes.push(shape);
    }

    return shapes;
}
```

After creating the queue, the code passes the queue to the function below every frame.

```
int Map::Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, queue<sf::RectangleShape*> map_queue)
{
    while (!map_queue.empty())
    {
        window.draw(*map_queue.front());
        map_queue.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1asdasdasdadasdasdsaawww122222222222222222222222
yeeeedasdasds

Comment: Does `texture.loadFromFile` succeed?  What value is it returning?

Comment: Consider a [mcve] so we can see the full picture. The texture might be loaded correctly and there is an error later in the code that fails to show it. Since using relative paths is often an issue try substituting the full path of the file and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: It's returning true

Comment: If it's returning true, that means all the code you show here is working correctly.  Your problem is not shown here.

Comment: Basically my code creates a rectangle and defines a texture for it and in the main loop it draws the rectangle

Comment: Let's say `ReadFile` works perfectly. We still have no idea how the queue that is returned is used later in the program to display anything. You're going to need to spend some time narrowing down the problem. I'd suggest starting from scratch and creating the simplest program that displays a texture so you have a baseline. If that works and your larger program does not then you can look for differences. If it doesn't work then you have something you can show here for help if you are unable to fix it yourself.

Comment: Everything is working perfectly, the only problem is that when I load the texture through the Map.cpp class it doesn't appear, and when I load it through Main.cpp it does. I believe that the correction would be to load the textures through Main.cpp, however, the code will be a mess.

Comment: If the data is not being displayed then everything is not working perfectly. Where does the loaded data go? What is the difference between the way that works and the way that doesn't? This should be a very easy problem to solve with a debugger and stepping through the code.

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php. white square problem. Your texture is local. SetTexture only hands a reference to object, it doesnt copy it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```cpp
 sf::Texture texture;
 texture.loadFromFile(word);
 shape->setTexture(&texture);
```

You create texture. load from file. set it to shape. then it gets deleted.

IMPORTANT:
shape.setTexture() sets the texture of the shape VIA pointer. the ADRESS of the texture is used. Because its address, and because after the "if" in which this piece of code is, the texture is deleted, your shape does NOT have the correct texture because the texture you gave it does not exist.

Solution: Wherever you create the shapes, also create the textures OR use textures as dynamic variables

example:

```cpp
class someSprite
{
public:
sf::Sprite spr;
sf::Texture tex;
}

int main()
{
someSprite spr;
spr.tex.loadFromFile("image.png");
spr.spr.setTexture(tex);
}
```

or

```cpp
int main()
{
sf::Sprite spr;
sf::Texture *tex = new sf::Texture;
tex->loadFromFile("image.png");

//and then when ur done with the texture:
delete spr.getTexture()
```